# Can't run Spring Tool Suite installer on Mac OS mavericks?

Tags: java, macos, operating-system, osx-mavericks, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

Whenever I unpack dmg installer I see image containing launcher something like - "Installer - spring-tool-suite-3.6.0.CI-B1808453-e4 ". After I try to launch this installer the loading indicator hangs a little, disappears and nothing happens. I am being forced to migrate to Mac OS due to work environment. I can't even launch the installer.

I suspect this is due to default Apple Java (whatever that means I am not OS X expert) being deleted on this laptop and JDK8 is on the home path.

ALE:~$ echo ${JAVA_HOME}
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0.jdk/Contents/Home/

Well, this forces me to migrate to IntelliJ, but I can't just believe that because of someone else fashion I can't do the work usual way...

Any hint? I don't even get error message..

Comment: Just install STS plugin for Eclipse.

Comment: I want to fix the problem. Or at least understand it.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same issue - download .tar.gz instead of .dmg distribution. There (sts-bundle/sts-3.X.X.RELEASE/STS.app) you'll have STS.app it should run.

Comment: @Aubergine the problem in your case is that you (most likely) have Java SE 7, but to open "Installer-Spring Tool Suite 3.X.X.RELEASE.app" you need a Java SE 6 runtime. Naturally I got such message right after I figured out the above way.

Comment: It does not matter which java distrubtion you have. Please see if you can fix dmg installation using the solution I provided.

Comment: But if you doubt inside the .ini file from the solution you have: -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6 , so you can change it. I didn't need though. I migrated in the end to IntelliJ after 5 years on eclipse..

Answer (score 0):

Since there is an interest around the question I will post the valid solution. Now what I did which caused an error - deleted default mac os java, and installed java 8 as HOME. Now Eclipse (STS, JasperSoftStudio or whatever) which was installed using dmg will look up the java not anywhere near your HOME directory. (even if it is inside Library as it should be).

**Solution:** Go to eclipse distribution directory (typically under applications) find the launcher, right click on the launcher, "show package contents", go to MacOS folder, open the .ini file(will have different name for different distributions) and locate -vim entry which statically points to some mac os location attempting to find java lib which is not there and never should be. Make sure your java home path is set, as now it will start to behave normally and look up home path.

If this still did not fix the issue, attempt to delete workspace folder if left from previous installation(or rename it) and play with Locked/Unlocked on the launcher properties. However the last two options are rather dances around the fire to summon spirits. **The first suggestion should work 100%.**

Make sure the error we are solving is something like: "Unable to locate plugin bla bla" in the error log.

All the best.